# How does one reduce a list of string-type workday data-items (date, working hours) into a list of workday-range strings each with total working hours?

Tags: javascript, arrays, mapreduce, mapping, reduce

I have an Array of Dates that I'm trying to concatenate to make a date range in javascript.

[Update]: What I've been attempted so far is splitting each month/day/year/hours into their own arrays, performing functionality to get the day range, (trying) to splice out the months so they would line up with the updated concatenated day range and then lastly needing to then add all of the hours for the days that were concatenated.

So the starting array:

```
["Nov 23 2021 8 hrs", "Nov 24 2021 8 hrs", "Nov 27 2021 8 hrs", "Dec 3 2021 8 hrs"]
```

Should be:

```
["Nov 23-24 2021 16 hrs", "Nov 27 2021 8 hrs", "Dec 3 2021 8 hrs"]
```

I am able to successfully split out the array indexes, push the date numbers into a new array, concatenate those, but im having trouble figuring out how to get rid of the extra month indexes based on any date after the first one.

heres the code for the day concatenation:

```
const getDayRanges = (array) => {
  var ranges = [],
    rstart,
    rend;
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    rstart = array[i];
    rend = rstart;
    while (array[i + 1] - array[i] == 1) {
      rend = array[i + 1]; // increment the index if the numbers sequential
      i++;
    }
    ranges.push(rstart == rend ? rstart + "" : rstart + " to " + rend);
  }
  return ranges;
};
```

I'm guessing im going to need to either pass in the whole array and have it specifically look for array[i] in a nested for loop, or perhaps add a new parameter to that function for months/years etc to compare the indexes? Im a little stuck on how to do that specifically though.

Comment: I don't exactly understand by what criteria you want to "merge" the dates in the input array. Is it by year/month or something else? Can please you elaborate on that? You can update your question to reflect that )

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, I updated my info above to hopefully clarify what i'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is a classic `map`/`reduce` task.**

Following steps have to be taken ...

1. [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the raw input data into a convenient working format and sort each item by date (and hours).
2. After mapping, [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the data-items by trying to find ranges of consecutive (or same) days.
3. After the initial map/reduce task (steps 1+2), `map` again; this time the reduced range-item data into either a special stringified range representation or into the original input format.

In addition ...

- one not only has to take care of normal day ranges within a month, but also ranges which span across months or even years.
- one has to come up with a regex which enables the extraction of an original string's `data` and `hours` values ...

  - [`/(?<date>[A-Za-z]+\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{4})\s+(?<hours>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+hrs/`](https://regex101.com/r/4uXdA4/1/)

```js
function createWorkDayItem(record) {
  const regXWorkDayData
    = /(?<date>[A-Za-z]+\s+\d{1,2}\s+\d{4})\s+(?<hours>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)\s+hrs/;
  const {
    date = null,
    hours = null,
  } = regXWorkDayData.exec(record)?.groups ?? {};

  return {
    record,
    hours: (hours !== null) ? Number(hours) : hours,
    date,
    time: (date !== null) ? new Date(date).getTime() : date,
  };
}
function compareWorkDayItems(a, b) {
  return a.time - b.time || b.hours - a.hours;
}

function collectItemOfSameOrConsecutiveDay(listOfRanges, currentItem, idx, arr) {
  if (idx >= 1) {
    const recentRange = listOfRanges.at(-1);
    const recentRangeItem = recentRange.at(-1);

    const deltaT = Number(
      ((currentItem.time - recentRangeItem.time) / 1000 /60 / 60 / 24) // msec => day(s)
        .toFixed(4)
    );
    if (deltaT <= 1/* day*/) {

      recentRange.push(currentItem)
    } else {
      listOfRanges.push([currentItem]);
    }
  } else {
    listOfRanges.push([currentItem]);
  }
  return listOfRanges;
}

function createWorkDayRangeFormat(rangeItem) {
  let result;
  if (rangeItem.length === 1) {

    result = rangeItem[0].record;
  } else {
    const totalHours = rangeItem
      .reduce((total, { hours }) => total + hours, 0);

    const [monthStart, dayStart, yearStart]
      = rangeItem[0].date.split(/\s+/);

    const [monthEnd, dayEnd, yearEnd]
      = rangeItem.at(-1).date.split(/\s+/);

    if (yearStart === yearEnd) {
      if (monthStart === monthEnd) {
        result = [

          monthStart,
          [dayStart, dayEnd].join('-'),
          yearStart,

        ].join(' ');
      } else {
        result = [[

          [monthStart, dayStart].join(' '),
          [monthEnd, dayEnd].join(' '),

        ].join(' - '), yearEnd].join(' ');
      }
    } else {
      result = [

        [monthStart, dayStart, yearStart].join(' '),
        [monthEnd, dayEnd, yearEnd].join(' '),

      ].join(' - ')
    }
    result = [result, totalHours, 'hrs'].join(' ');
  }
  return result;
}

const workDayHourList = [
  "Nov 23 2021 8 hrs", 
  "Nov 24 2021 4.5 hrs", 
  "Nov 24 2021 2.5 hrs",

  "Nov 27 2021 8 hrs",
  "Dec 3 2021 8 hrs",
  
  "Dec 16 2021 2.25 hrs",
  "Dec 18 2021 7.75 hrs",
  "Dec 17 2021 6.5 hrs",

  "Dec 1 2021 4 hrs",
  "Nov 30 2021 6 hrs",

  "Dec 31 2020 3.5 hrs",
  "Dec 30 2020 4.25 hrs",
  "Jan 02 2021 3.75 hrs",
  "Jan 01 2021 2.25 hrs",
];

console.log(
  '1st ... map the raw input data and sort it by date and hours ...',
  workDayHourList
    .map(createWorkDayItem)
    .sort(compareWorkDayItems)
);
console.log(
  '2nd ...after mapping, reduce the data by trying to find ranges of consecutive days ...',
  workDayHourList
    .map(createWorkDayItem)
    .sort(compareWorkDayItems)
    .reduce(collectItemOfSameOrConsecutiveDay, [])
);
console.log(
  '3rd ... after initial map/reduce, map again, the reduced (range) date into either a special range or into the original input format ...',
  workDayHourList
    .map(createWorkDayItem)
    .sort(compareWorkDayItems)
    .reduce(collectItemOfSameOrConsecutiveDay, [])
    .map(createWorkDayRangeFormat)
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This looks promising, thanks for coding that out, ill give it a try some point soon and comment back if it worked.

Comment: *"...looks promising"* ... you're kidding. ... *"...if it worked."* ... there is a test which does cover edge cases the OP did not even take into account yet.

Comment: Haha I didnt mean to imply it wouldnt work. I didnt get to dig into everything you implemented so I couldnt speak on whether all of it applied to what I needed it to do but I saw your end results and it calculated everything exactly like I was asking for. I also noticed you took into account if the year carried over into the next year which is perfect. So once again, thank you very much for coding that up.

Comment: @Logikev ... thanks for the clarification. You're certainly welcome, and take all the time it needs to dig into the code/approach. Also don't hesitate asking in case there are any questions left.

Comment: Works perfectly as expected, thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I think the logic of keeping dates with hours is flawed. If you keep the hours separately, like in a Map, or in a two-dimensional array, it would be much easier to achieve what you want, with Date.parse and new Date, you can check the dates. Something like this:

```
let date = new Date(Date.parse('Nov 23 2021')) 
let date1 = new Date(Date.parse('Nov 24 2021')) 
//and use Date methods to compare them
```

Otherwise you have to create an algorithm to match regular expression in order to find the date and hours, keep them, compare them, combine them, and add them to a new list.

Comment: What the OP tries to achieve is a little bit more complex.

Comment: @peterseliger I didn't provide the whole answer. Yeah, that's why I said it makes it a step easier. Looping through the array, finding dates that are a perfect sequence with no gap, adding their hours, putting them in a list as one with a date range and their added hours, and if the array is not in order, one step harder.

Comment: Yeah, what I have been doing is splitting the array based on their index and pushing them into new arrays. So I could split out the dates into their own array do what you're suggesting. I guess that would still leave me unsure about how to say add up all of the hours for those date ranges based on the ones that were concatenated.

Comment: I can't provide you with the perfect answer right now, but if you split them in a Map let's say, you have to find the sequence in dates, and just put the first and last date in a sequence found like - ['Nov 24 2021 - Nov 27 2021'] => 45hours.  and add their hours. Sometimes the best solution is to rebuild your logic. IMHO. But if you really want to use this format you don't have any choice to use a very complicated and long algorithm.